# Creating eset object from preprocessed expression matrix?

Tags: r, expression, bioinformatics, bayesian, bioconductor

I am analysing with R some gene expression data. I would like to do differential gene expression analysis with limma's eBayes (limma is part of BioConductor), but to do that I need to have my expression data as an eset object. Thing is, I have only preprocessed data and do not have the CEL files, I could convert directly to eset object. I tried searching from Internet, but couldn't find a solution. Only thing I found, was that it IS possible.

**Why eBayes:**
It should have robust results even with only two or three samples in some of the groups and I do indeed have 3 groups that are from 2 to 3 samples in size.

**In detail what I have and want to do:**
I have expression data, already as logarithmic, normalized intesity values. The data is in expression matrix. There is about 20 000 rows and each row is a gene and the rownames are the official gene names. There is 22 columns and each column corresponds to one cancer sample. I have different kinds of cancer subtypes there and would like to compare for example subtype 1 samples' gene expression to that of the group 2's. Below is a two row, 5 column example of what my matrix would look like.

**Example matrix:**

```
       SAMP1   SAMP2   SAMP3   SAMP4   SAMP5
GENE1  123.764 122.476 23.4764 2.24343 123.3124
GENE2  224.233 455.111 124.122 112.155 800.4516
```

**The problem:**
To evaluate the differential gene expression with eBayes I would need the eset object out of this expression data and I have honestly no idea how to go about that step. :(

I am very grateful for every bit of info that can help me out! If someone can suggest another reliable method for small sample size comparisons, that might solve my problem as well.

Thank you!

Comment: this vignette should help you -   http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/Biobase/inst/doc/ExpressionSetIntroduction.R

Comment: ExpressionSet() seems to work! Thank you! I had tried it out earlier, but did not have good enough example to figure out why it did not like my data. Turns out, it was stored as data frame...

Comment: Analysis generally starts with `lmFit`, rather than `eBayes`, and `lmFit` takes a matrix; from `?lmFit`: "object: object of class 'numeric', 'matrix', 'MAList', 'EList',
          'marrayNorm', 'ExpressionSet' or 'PLMset' containing
          log-ratios or log-values of expression for a series of
          microarrays". Also, questions about Bioconductor questions are better asked on the Bioconductor [mailing list](
http://bioconductor.org/help/mailing-list/)

Comment: Using an `ExpressionSet` seems to be quite similar to a `SummarizedExperiment` which is also prevalent in Bioconductor packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an `ExpressionSet` seems to be quite similar to a `SummarizedExperiment` which is also prevalent in Bioconductor packages. From what I understand, there is nothing special about using one or the other in a package--in my experience, it's considered as a generalized container for data in order to standardize the data set format across Bioconductor packages.

From the vignette on Bioconductor:

> Affymetrix data will usually be normalized using the
>   affy
>   package.  We will assume here that the
>   data is available as an
>   ExpressionSet
>   object called
>   eset.  Such an object will have an slot containing
>   the  log-expression  values  for  each  gene  on  each  array  which  can  be  extracted  using
>   exprs(eset).

In other words, there's nothing special about the data for the ExpressionSet. An `ExpressionSet` is simply a bunch of related experimental data strung together into one, but it appears that I can create a new object just from the regular object:

```
library(limma)

# counts is the assay data I already have.
dim(counts)
# [1] 64102     8

# Creates a new ExpressionSet object (quite bare, only the assay data)
asdf <- ExpressionSet(assayData = counts)

# Returns the data you put in.
exprs(asdf)
```

This works on my setup.

**The second part that you need to consider is the design of the differential expression analysis comparison model matrix.** You will need predefined factors to go along with your samples (probably within a `phenoData` argument to `ExpressionSet` and then create a `model.matrix` using R's special `formula` syntax. They look similar to: `dependent ~ factor1 + factor2 + co:related`. Note that a `factor1` is a factor *category* or dimension, not just one level.

Once you have that, you should be able to run `lmFit`. I've actually not used `limma` much before but it appears to be similar to `edgeR`'s scheme.

Comment: Yes, it was working fine in the end, as in your example. I had simply my data in wrong object format. Thank you for your reply and clear example. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just decided to make it answer to help some other poor sod, who has the same accident. Figured the problem out myself after going through the links kindly given in comments.

ExpressionSet() does take matrices and turn them to eSet object fine. Just had to make sure the data was as matrix instead of data frame object.